# Modify headers of a app with extension using chrome 45

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I developed a app and extension, the extension should add some special headers in order to know if the user has our extension installed and verify some security issues.

Users install our app through our server in a wizard, firstly install the extension and later the app.

Before Google Chrome 45 when a user launch our app the server detect the headers (added by the extension) , validate the user and redirect to a client page. After update 
Google Chrome (v45), the headers are ignored and never sent with the request.

Only when uninstall the application the extension works and add all required headers, if install the app again, then the extension stop working.

Debugging into this, I see, if the url of app and the url patterns to modify the headers match, Google Chrome ignore the changes done by the extension.

Is possible modify header of our app using our extension?.. is a bug or is required add some new permissions?

Comment: Is knowing that the extension is installed the only thing you need?

Comment: I post this issue in google

[issue: 527878](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527878)

see attached sample, thanks

Comment: @RafaelSantos Do you really want to modify the request via an extension, or is it sufficient to have a method that inserts a custom header value from an extension in the request?

Comment: Yes, should be our extension, its a enterprise extension with some automation scripts and a security key for each client. Our extension works fine before chrome 45

Answer (score 1):

[It's a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=526413); sorry, I could not reply earlier since it's a result of a security fix that was not public before.

This is expected to be fixed at least in Chrome 46, but probably will be ported back to 45 since this prompted much public outrage.